# How to configure a Translatable Entity in EasyAdmin?

Tags: symfony, translation, easyadmin

I'm using [Translatable](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/blob/main/doc/translatable.md#personal-translations) and EasyAdmin in a Symfony 5 project and I have configured 2 languages.

The issue is I need to be able to edit the different languages of a record in EasyAdmin, I have checked the docs of Translatable, EasyAdmin and Symfony, There is very little information about how to integrate database translations into EasyAdmin.

Therefore, I'm a bit stuck in terms of code, I have tried configuring `setTranslationParameters()` inside the entity CRUD controller and changing some configuration in the `DashboardController` however, I don't think this is the right approach.

Any suggestions of how to solve this issue?
Thank you for your effort and time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as of writing, this feature doesn't exist in EasyAdmin, please see the link to the answer to the issue on Github.

https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/4982

However, a work around is possible with a different package:

1. remove `doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions` and then install [KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors)
2. install [a2lix/translation-form-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/a2lix/translation-form-bundle)
3. Create a translation field:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller\Admin\Field;

use A2lix\TranslationFormBundle\Form\Type\TranslationsType;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Contracts\Field\FieldInterface;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\FieldTrait;

final class TranslationField implements FieldInterface
{
    use FieldTrait;

    public static function new(string $propertyName, ?string $label = null, array $fieldsConfig = []): self
    {
        return (new self())
            ->setProperty($propertyName)
            ->setLabel($label)
            ->setFormType(TranslationsType::class)
            ->setFormTypeOptions([
                'default_locale' => 'cz',
                'fields' => $fieldsConfig,
            ]);
    }
}
```

4. Use the `TranslationField` inside your admin CRUD controller:

```php
    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            TextField::new('title', 'title')->hideOnForm(),
            TranslationField::new('translations', 'translations', [
                'title' => [
                    'field_type' => TextType::class,
                    'required' => true,
                ]
                // add more translatable properties into the array
            ])->setRequired(true)
                ->hideOnIndex()
        ];
    }
```